# Troubleshooting Windows 1803 and newer won't install?

Tags: windows-10

I've got a pretty simple Asus P6T Core i7 build.  On the very latest BIOS version, 6 GB RAM, 500 GB disk space using the built in RAID 0 across a pair of 250 GB SATA drives.  Other than the RAID, this is a very plain/ordinary machine.  As far as software goes the only things on it are the Chrome browser and the latest version of OpenOffice.  Not the newest hardware by any means, but I've got older (and far less powerful) machines running Windows 10 1903 with no problem.  This particular machine though is stuck on Windows 10 1709.  1803, 1809, and 1903 all appear to install fine, but then the machine won't boot afterwards.  Locks up with the Windows logo before the dots start spinning.  If I hard reset a time or 2 it will automatically revert back to 1709 and then operate fine again.

Any thoughts on getting this machine to run the current build of Windows 10?  Logs I should check, etc, to at least narrow down the problem?  Any known issues with the motherbord or RAID controller?  I hate to spend all the time rebuilding without RAID only to find myself in the same boat, so have not tried that yet.  It's got what was a decent (for the time) Nvidia graphics card, but should I look at replacing that first?

Comment: Try to disable Secure Boot in the BIOS. You may also need a newer RAID driver - is this a hardware RAID?

Comment: The install is obviously failing and rolling back. This is a good thing though, because that means the installer itself detects a problem and tells you about it in the log. All you need to do is check the log. If my memory serves me right its located in C:\Windows.BT~\setuplog.txt or something like that.

Comment: @harrymc I do not see any Secure Boot option in this BIOS.  This is the onboard motherboard RAID.  It claims to be "J-Micron".  I have no special drivers nor have ever installed any.  It "just worked" out of the box (at least until now?).

Comment: @LPChip Very nice, never knew about the $Windows.BT stuff before!  Read the logs (many, MANY MB of them) manually and it looks like everything is a success and then it's suddenly rolling back...  Found the setupdiag.exe tool to automatically parse those logs and all that reports is a generic boot failure.  Looking like more evidence that Microsoft changed something starting with 1803 that makes it not be compatible with something in my hard drive subsystem somewhere.  I guess the real test would be to scare up a spare drive, disconnect the RAID, and try installing on that new drive native.

Comment: Which driver are you using for the JMicron?

Comment: I did read something about people having problems with attached storage devices, such as external harddisks, external flash card readers with a card in them, external phones seen as flash drives etc. Microsoft suggests to remove all external devices prior to doing the upgrade. Not sure this is something applicable to your case though

Comment: @LPChip Good thought, I do have an external USB backup drive, but removing it before doing the update does not help

Comment: I'm afraid I may have my answer. "Intel Desktop/Workstation/Server Express Chipset RAID", version 13.44.0.1026 dated 2/22/2017 is the driver. Appears to be built in to Windows 10 as "iaStorAV.sys". Googling returns little directly applicable (mostly those suspicious "driver download" sites).  However, one of them does list this driver as being removed from Windows 10 starting in version 1803, which matches up nicely with my symptoms. Argh. Anyone have any luck porting forward drivers? I suspect there's a good reason it was dropped though. Looking like reinstall on the non-RAID controller :-(

Comment: Spent a number of hours stripping the machine down to bare minimum and retrying installs.  Even with just a standard SATA interface 1803+ still fail.  Appears to be something about this motherboard.  I don't get it, everything about it is standard at this point, but newer versions of Windows 10 all crash with a failure to find the boot device.  Probably time for the scrap heap for this i7.  Sad because it's still such a fast machine...